# Espresso testing with RxLoader

Tags: android, rx-java, android-espresso

I have an activity that uses RxLoader to fetch data from server upon activity creation, and populates a list view. I also have test code that tries to click the first row of the list view after it's populated.

Because I am using RxLoader, I have to write a customized IdlingResource for Espresso. However, the problem is that the test finishes (fails) before my listview is populated.

Here is my Activity code:

```
        RxLoaderManager.get(this).create(
            "my_loader",
            mRestService.loadData(),
            new RxLoaderObserver<MyData>() {
                @Override
                public void onNext(MyData data) {
                    // populate listview with data here
                    ...
                }
  });
```

Here is my IdlingResource implementation:

```
public class IdlingApiServiceWrapper implements IdlingResource {

public Observable<MyData> loadData(){
    counter.incrementAndGet();
    Observable<MyData> observable = api.loadData().finallyDo(new Action0() {
        @Override
        public void call() {
            counter.decrementAndGet();
            notifyIdle();
        }
    });
    return observable;
```

}
}

Problem is that: When I run the test code, the method "counter.decrementAndGet()" is always called before the "onNext()" method in my activity. My test fails because it expects to listview to be populated.

Apparently I am doing something wrong. But what am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

Here is a cleaner code snippet to illustrate the problem:

```
        RxLoaderManager.get(this).create(
            "my_loader",
            myObservable.finallyDo(new Action0() {
                @Override
                public void call() {
                    //log
                }
            }),
            new RxLoaderObserver<MyData>() {
                @Override
                public void onNext(MyData data) {
                // do something here
            }
        }).start();
```

In the above code, the code snippet within finallyDo() gets called before the "onNext()" call of the observer. Is finallyDo() supposed to be called after the "onNext()"?

Answer (score 1):

Evan Tatarka pointed me to the right direction: https://github.com/evant/rxloader/issues/14

Here is my final solution:

```
public class IdlingApiServiceWrapper implements IdlingResource {

public Observable<MyData> loadData() {
    counter.incrementAndGet();
    Observable<MyData> observable = api.loadData().finallyDo(new Action0() {
        @Override
        public void call() {
             new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    counter.decrementAndGet();
                    notifyIdle();
                }
            });
        }
    });
    return observable;
}
```

}